# Can not open ms database 2003 format with MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access-2016

I converted my MS Access database to 2002-2003 format, opened it in MS 2010 and saved it as a .accdb.

According to MS I should be able to open it.  It has a workgroup file and I am opening it using ms access 2016 (32 bit) version. I am getting the error message "can not open a database with a previous version of your application".

I was wondering if I have to convert the workgroup also .mdw?  I don't see where you would make this conversion.  I get the same error message with or without invoking the mdw when opening the .accdb file.

Comment: Maybe you have saved it in the old format giving it the accdb extension. Otherwise it will work. The mdw file is not used with ACE - the new database version.